# What color financial time series are there?

Tags: time-series, finance, white-noise

There is a folklore white noise hypothesis related to (and equivalent to some forms of) the efficient market hypothesis in finance -see references below. But are there some asset pairs whose return time series (or perhaps some "natural" transforms of those time series) are approximately noises of another color than white ? -I ask as a nonspecialist, obviously.

Thank you.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2326311
https://www.lasu.edu.ng/publications/management_sciences/james_kehinde_ja_10.pdf
[http://www2.kobe-u.ac.jp/~motegi/WEB_max_corr_empirics_EJ_revise1_v12.pdf](http://www2.kobe-u.ac.jp/%7Emotegi/WEB_max_corr_empirics_EJ_revise1_v12.pdf)
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8450754/
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0256090919930203
http://www.ijhssnet.com/journals/Vol_2_No_22_Special_Issue_November_2012/23.pdf

Comment: Perhaps try Economics Stack Exchange instead. (Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange might be another option, but they do not appreciate beginner questions.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Richard Hardy, i didn't know there were such stackexchanges -though i did briefly search, but it seems not with the right prompts. Note that it is more a research question than a beginner question -as even the white noise case is a matter of research as can be seen in the references above.